# updated to IE explorer 11. Marco update is not working

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, macros

I just updated to IE11.  Just made an update to my report (macro) and it's giving me a run time error... run-time error'13': type mismatch.  When I debug, below is where it's taking me to - specifically Set pDocument = IE.document... Can you help please.  Thank you so much

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

     IE.navigate "https://famis.web.fedex.com/fwr/menus/menu-15-a.cfm?chgDiv=1&Division=09"


With IE
    .Top = 1
    .Left = 1
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 600
End With

IE.Visible = True

    Do While IE.Busy
    Loop


    Dim pDocument As IHTMLDocument2
    Dim pElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim pElement As IHTMLElement
    Set pDocument = IE.document
    Set pElements = pDocument.all

Worksheets("Setup").Range("A10").Value = IE.LocationName



If IE.LocationName = "SSO Login" Then
```

Comment: While debug, enter `? TypeName(IE.document)` in Immediate window to check the actual type. What Excel version are you using - 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: What references do you have enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the reference : Microsoft HTML Object Library is checked.

You can go in Tools/References in the VBA editor.